# Flask Blueprint setup with SQLAlchemy gives UnboundExecutionError

Tags: python, flask

I am using Flask to build an experimental application using Blueprint. Here is my project's structure:

```
-myproject/
 requirements.txt
 run.py
 -apps/
  -static/
  -template/
  -database/
  __init__.py
  views.py
  model.py
  auth.py
  message.py
```

I init my app in **init**.py, using blueprint to integrate other parts of the app.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
from .views import views
from .model import model, db
from .auth import auth, login_manager

db.init_app(app)

app.register_blueprint(views)
app.register_blueprint(model)
app.register_blueprint(auth)
```

Then in `views.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, render_template, session, g, url_for, Blueprint
views = Blueprint('views', __name__)
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, relation, sessionmaker

# ORM Session
orm_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
@views.route('/courses')
def courses():
    courses = orm_session.query(Course).order_by('-id')
    return render_template('courses.html', courses=courses)
```

My `Course` class is defined in `model.py`:

```
class Course(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'course'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    subjects = db.relationship('Subject', secondary='course_subject_link')
    students = db.relationship('Student', secondary='course_student_link')
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{0}:{1.name}:{1.subjects!r}:{1.students!r}>".format(Course, self)
```

In template folder, I have put something like `{% for course in courses %}` and `{% set active_page = "courses" %}` in the template file. When I run the app, it gives me this error:

```
UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on mapper Mapper|Course|course, SQL expression or this Session
```

I did not use Blueprint before so the app used to be able to run. But after I used Blueprint the urls seem to be broken. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what the problem is.

From the hint in the error message I guess that I forget to create_engine and pass the engine to sessionmaker using `bind=engine`.

Here is the code I changed in `views.py`:

```
from os.path import join, dirname 
_cwd = dirname(__file__)
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + join(_cwd, 'database/courses.sqlite'))
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
orm_session = Session()
```

Here `database/courses.sqlite` is the location of my database file.

Comment: I would suggest that you edit the answer to better describe your solution and then accept it